# Excel VBA Only Run The First Click mouse_event

Tags: excel, vba, mouseevent

Please Help,

I want excel to run multiple clicking on certain mouse coordinate.
But, unfortunately excel only run on the first mouse_event.

Here's my code :

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub ClickAgain()

SetCursorPos 1842, 17   'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

SetCursorPos 466, 43   'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

SetCursorPos 292, 300   'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

SetCursorPos 345, 330   'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably you need to wait some amount of time between the clicks.

Comment: Thank for reply, I had use this code, but the result is same :
 Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Comment: Why not consider "run on change" of a particular cell?

Comment: How much sleep did you put between your clicks?

Comment: Solar Mike : I want to control another program from excel vba, it needs multiple click
PEH : 5000